# Zend Framework Herança de classes - Módulos com Prefixo

Tags: php, zend

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em PHP com *Zend Framework* e estou com o seguinte problema:

Criei uma classe chamada BaseController no meu módulo "Admin".
Setei a opção:

```
resources.frontController.prefixDefaultModule = "true"
```

Portanto, os nomes dos meus controllers são "Admin_IndexController", "Admin_UsuarioController" e etc.

Preciso que "Admin_IndexController" extends "Admin_BaseController" (uma classe também criada por mim) porém, recebo apenas a mensagem de que a classe não foi encontrada.

Obs.: Já tentei renomear a classe para "Admin_BaseController" ou apenas "BaseController" ou implementar em "Admin_IndexController" o código

```
class Admin_IndexController extends Admin_BaseController
```

ou

```
class Admin_IndexController extends Basecontroller
```

e nenhuma opção resolveu o problema.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que poderia ser?

Comment: Não sei exatamente qual seria o problema. Mas porque você precisa do prefixo, porque você não faz apenas usando os namespaces. Exemplo. "namespace Admin; class IndexController extends BaseController". Sendo que BaseController foi declarado no namespace Admin também.

Comment: Uma outra sugestão, já que não está achando a classe, (eu faço isso quando acontece comigo). Eu sigo o autoload (uso o autoload do composer) e vejo aonde ele está parando, o que ele não está conseguindo achar. Talvez assim você consiga entender o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou isso:

**require('BaseController.php');**

No controller que irá herdar do BaseController.